# Como criar uma lista de programas bloqueados em C#?

Tags: c#, lista, processo

Quero que ao selecionar um dos programas da lista de programas instalados no Windows, ele possa ser bloqueado. Quero impedir eles de serem abertos, no caso, com uma senha.

Por exemplo, selecionar, clicar em bloquear, e adicionar uma senha para se conectar ao programa bloqueado.

Segue um exemplo do que eu quero fazer, na verdade, é algo parecido com a função controle dos pais, para definir quais os programas podem ser executados:

[image: Esse é o exemplo do que eu quero fazer.]

Eu pensei em listar os programas em uma listbox, e ao selecionar o programa, ele procurar pelo processo, assim então, podendo o mesmo ser bloqueado.
Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Oi, Wesley, quando o pessoal pede mais informações nos comentários, seu trabalho é [edit] a pergunta pra acrescentar detalhes. Depois é só notificar a pessoa usando o arroba `@fulano atualizei a pergunta`

Comment: @brasofilo Desculpa, eu não sabia. Primeira pergunta aqui. Na verdade, eu criei a conta com o objetivo de fazer essa pergunta por que tenho pouco tempo pra conseguir resolver isso.
Mas obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode começar a resolver seu problema em partes. Este link mostra como listar os programas instalados no windows -> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-list-of-installed-software-in-local-machine-using-c-sharp-code1.

2 Tente descobrir como pegar um software que está sendo inicializado->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284674/how-do-i-stop-an-application-from-opening

3 Liste os softwares que estão na sua lista com os que estão sendo inicializados. Listar os softwares que você deseja que sejam bloqueados é muito fácil e existem vários tutoriais que explicam isso (É o básico)

Em fim, tente fazer em partes. Isso que acabei de mostrar é uma parte de várias formas de resolver o mesmo problema. 
Outra coisa tente pesquisar em inglês só resultado das buscas será surpreendente.

Espero ter dado uma ideia de começar seu projeto!